# Increment Record Position in Database (via LINQ or TSQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, t-sql, linq-to-sql

I have a table (in SQL Server) like:

```
UserId    CompanyId    UserName    Position
     1            1    John        1
     2            2    Adam        1
     3            2    Nick        2
     4            1    Mark        2
     5            3    Jack        1
```

UserId is the PK with autoincrement. CompanyID is a FK. Position is just a sequential counter for the users (per company).

When a new user record is inserted (via LINQ) for a company, I want the Position to be incremented as well. Currently I get the MAX+1 of the Position for the given CompanyId and then assign it to the new record. The problem is that concurrent insert operations often result in identical Position values.

I tried incrementing the position in an insert trigger for uniqueness, but LINQ doesn't reflect the updated value automatically.

How can I go about fixing this through LINQ-to-SQL or directly as a TSQL query?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried getting exclusive lock on table using db transaction while setting position?

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh I'm trying to avoid locking the table, but I'll have a look at wrapping it in a transaction.

Comment: You could go back to trigger solution if you set [IsDbGenerated to true](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.isdbgenerated%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [AutoSync to OnInsert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.autosync%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you about TSQL query.
you can use 
**IDENT_CURRENT** - which gives you the last id inserted into the table **by anyone**.
if that is not what you want than try - SCOPE_IDENTITY

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents:

```
begin transaction
    declare @v int
    select @v = isnull((select max(field2)+1 from t1), 1)
    insert into t1 (field2) values (@v)
commit transaction

-- just checking
select * from t1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [unique constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on `CompanyID` and `Position` to prevent duplicates.

```
create table Users
(
  UserId int identity primary key,
  CompanyId int not null,
  UserName char(10) not null,
  Position int not null,
  unique(CompanyId, Position)
)
```

Instead of duplicates you get an exception and in your code you can do something about that like perhaps a retry.